# Is it possible to Swizzle NSAttributedString.init(string:attributes)?

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, method-swizzling

I am trying to swizzle `NSAttributedString` but getting a compile error:

```swift
extension NSAttribtuedString {

   @objc convenience init(swizzledString: String, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any?] {
       .....
   }
}
```

**Error**

```
Method cannot be marked @objc because type of parameter 2 cannot be represented in Objective C
```

The error makes sense. Any way we can solve this to keep the function signature and swizzle the init function?

Comment: why did you use `@objc` tag for convenience initializer?

Comment: @emrcftci because I need to swizzle it

Answer (score 1):

You get the error, because swift's dictionary type does not exist in objective-c. You would have to use NSDictionary:

```
@objc convenience init(swizzledString:String, attributes:NSDictionary)
```